# Rep League: The same user appears twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, stackexchange.com

[image]

Comment: Looks like this [Nick Craver] guy is the new man?

Comment: @litb, yes.  However, that is very unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed that user and 9 others.  We'll keep an eye on this to see if we can figure out how they're getting in there twice.

Comment: This bug has reappeared