# Doubled users in the reputation leagues

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

If you look at any site's reputation league for the current week, month, quarter or year (but not for any past week, month, quarter or year), every user appears twice.

This seems related to [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62145/rep-league-the-same-user-appears-twice) (which is marked as completed), but that one only affected a few users, while this time every single user seems to be affected.

Note that this also affects meta, so it does not seem to be a side-effect of the server move.

Proof screenshot:

[image: Doubled users]

Comment: It's just recognition that Nick Craver really *is* that good.

Comment: @Jon, it's so nice to see that coming from someone unbiased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a different bug than the one linked: instead of duping one user for all time it duped all users for one day.  I've deleted the dupes for now, but more work is needed to figure out what actually went wrong.