# Missing from Month Reputation List

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues, user-rank

This is a followup to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153042/user-league-information-missing-in-the-profile-page).  The **top x% this month** has returned to the summary profile page but if I click the link on my profile, I am missing from the monthly league listing:

[image]

If I change the league to week, quarter, year or all-time I can find my listing but not for month.

Is this due to the issue Nick Craver mentioned in the other answer?

> we have an issue with the leagues population causing an inordinate
>   amount of load on our SQL servers which I have yet to find time to
>   investigate.

Comment: I've seen this before, together with other names being doubled. Can't find the old meta post for that at the moment though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I noticed that there are duplicates listed in the league as well

Comment: Bingo: possible duplicate of [Doubled users in the reputation leagues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68419/doubled-users-in-the-reputation-leagues)

Comment: @MartijnPieters not really a duplicate because I am asking why I am missing from the month rep league.

Comment: It's the same underlying bug; read through the linked posts from there (for example [I'm ranked twice in the leagues!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149392) You fell out because of the underlying SQL structures changing rapidly. The *second* answer on that one shows it causes users dropping out as well as users being doubled).

Comment: @MartijnPieters well look at that, I never would have found that answer. thanks

Comment: Hmm... bit of a stretch for a "duplicate," but this _is_ Meta, where we close as dupes of FAQ entries, so I guess it's okay. Hopefully the explanatory comments stay where they are.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I do have a similar issue and my name does not appear on any of the leagues (neither of week, quarter, month, year and all time). All search results are returning, "No use found ..."