# User reputation leagues - Everybody appears twice

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Jon Skeet now #2 in Reputation Leagues!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues)

Just noticed that every user in the reputation league (for example https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) appears twice:

[image]

Seems to have [happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62145/rep-league-the-same-user-appears-twice).

Comment: @Rick: You are right. Haven't seen that because the title itself wasn't really generic enough.

Comment: To be fair, there's no way he could be #2 without some sort of bug being involved. Do the math, he could leave the site forever and it would still take months for anyone to catch up. But yeah, not the most obvious title I guess. :P