# I'm ranked twice in the leagues!

Tags: bug, status-planned, reputation-leagues

I'm not as famous as [Jon Skeet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99502/jon-skeet-now-2-in-reputation-leagues) but I thought I'd file a bug report anyway for appearing twice.  [Here](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow)

[image: Bug report image]

FYI - I changed my user name within the period being viewed.

---

I wonder, is StackExchange hiring SQL programmers? I know how to get Unique values from a table!  As @Yannis has pointed out and I myself found, this bug keeps coming back like a bad dream.  The ones I looked at before I reported this looked like they affected all users, and I thought mine was unique.  In fact scrolling up the page I can see #6 Mihal Iorga is showing twice as well.

Comment: Related: [Rep League: The same user appears twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62145/rep-league-the-same-user-appears-twice?rq=1) & [Doubled users in the reputation leagues](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68419/doubled-users-in-the-reputation-leagues?lq=1) - Normally I'd vote to close as a duplicate, but since both the duplicates say [status-completed] I think the bug has re-surfaced and thus not really a duplicate.

Comment: And [undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/users/848164/undefined) and [Greg Hewgill](http://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill) are also shown twice. But what do you complain, I am not listed at all there, _I_ should shout murther.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Are you ranked #2 or #4, who are missing, by any chance?

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail I wish. No, #30, according to the [quarter league](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow).

Comment: Oh damn you `READ UNCOMMITTED`, we'll take a look.

Answer (score 13):

> I wonder, is StackExchange hiring SQL programmers? I know how to get Unique values from a table!

[Yes, we are!](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/23229/web-developer-q-a-team-stack-exchange?a=rrAqpLG)...but that's beside the point.

The issue here isn't solved by a `Distinct()` or any other simple means, because it's a high speed transactional problem.  The load on a single SQL server is kept down via dirty reads [using a `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471055/why-use-a-read-uncommitted-isolation-level).  The issue comes into play when thinking about how the leagues are generated.

Once a day we hit an API on the requested site that returns a massive list of users for that site along with their rep, ranks, and deltas for that period.  Think about what this means on Stack Overflow: Summing up every reputation event of **96,566** users (200+ rep) and doing these ranks.  But that aggregate query is done on our RepHistory table which contains records for all **723,181** users with reputation changes totaling **34,941,129** rows as of about 5 seconds ago.  None of those values are what I consider large, but they are significant and rapidly changing.

We can't do summations like this *with 100% accuracy* without locking the table, that's why READ UNCOMMITTED is used in our high transaction environment.

That's the why.  What do we plan to do about it?  I'll *probably* add a RepHistoryDaily table or some such that already sums up the day since that has multiple uses besides making these queries simpler.  That's the off-the-top-of-my-head plan.  But, we're coming up on some deadlines for moving our primary datacenter, so this will have to wait a while since that takes top priority and there's a lot of work left to get it done.

Comment: So this will be going on for a while? That could breathe new life into the Stack Overflow Store. "I was displayed twice in the Stack Overflow leagues and all I got was this lousy T-Shirt"

Comment: Is marking this now as status-declined means your plan has been cancelled?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - just some mis-communication there, tagged appropriately now

Answer (score 2):

Confirming.

Now [Mihai Iorga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204701/mihai-iorga) is [showing up twice as #6](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-10-01/204701?sort=reputationchange#204701), [as well as Richard the Kiwi](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-10-01/573261?sort=reputationchange#573261).

Also, **#2 and #4 seem to be missing**, which (net of the duplicates) <del>seems to give the correct total number of entries on the first page.</del>

**It's also counting the number of entries wrong: on the default 30 per page, it gives ranks #1, ..., #34 (inclusive) on the first page; 50 per page, up to #53 inclusive; 15 per page, up to #16 inclusive.

Screenshot:

[image: Unpossible!]

### Related

A similar issue occurs with different sorts (above is the default, by "month rank"). For example, if you sort by "Rank Change", [Mohamed KALLEL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1003575/mohamed-kallel) [shows up twice](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2012-10-01/1003575?sort=rankchange#1003575).

Comment: Of course, he changed from rank x to rank x-1, therefore that's two ranks in that change, so you show up twice.

Comment: @Xaade: What do you mean?