# A wrong status of Copy Editor badge is displayed in reviews

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, badge-progress

When hovering over the badge progress in the review queue, one is able to see his progress towards the badges of a particular review type, as well as Civil Duty, Electorate and Copy Editor. Now, I have the Copy Editor badge on my SO account, however it's progress in the review queue looks like this:
[image]

which is wrong since it shows the wrong number.

Comment: Converted answer as an comment: Something is really wrong. Because as per [all time editors states](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all&search=singerofthefall) you have edited `413` posts and Copy Editor requires 500 edited posts (excluding retag). So you are not eligible to get Copy Editor badge. I think badge-progress is okay. But you earned Copy Editors badge wrongly(by mistake-bug). It should be a bug.

Comment: Real mystery and it's full with numbers. Your [Revisions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1490355/singerofthefall?tab=activity) show 645 revisions. The user's [Editors tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all) show 414 edits for you. Badge was awarded back in September 20. Something here smells of a bug but maybe it's just misunderstanding of how things work.

Comment: The badge may count now deleted posts whereas the tooltip might not. That could explain the discrepancy and why you have already been awarded the badge.

Comment: @Chris, that would be a damn lot of deleted posts...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall - True, that's one reason I only commented rather than answering :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, yea, I'm really confused about it too... all pages show completely different numbers. I would understand if they'd differ by 1-2 posts, but this...

Comment: Actually the difference between revisions tab and editors tab can be explained; maybe you did many self edits (i.e. editing your own posts) which are not counted as "real" edits however can't see how you got that badge..

Comment: @SHaWizDowArd, I'm now wondering what will happen when the badge progress bar will hit 500...

Comment: Nothing, don't worry about that. Those badges are earned only once and can't be revoked. Keep in mind that users even keep badges received over posts there are now deleted. Whatever the reason is, the badge is yours. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The Revisions tab includes retags. Having a lot of edited posts eventually deleted isn't surprising if SingerOfTheFall often edits crappy questions as they come in (which is useful, to tell if the question merely needed to be translated into proper English or should be trashed).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your particular case we're going to have to blame cosmic rays:

[image: cosmic rays]

From time to time we do see data anomalies due to our use of `READ UNCOMMITTED` transactions while scanning our large volume of posts for badge awards.  You can read a brief bit of information about that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149392/im-ranked-twice-in-the-leagues/149506#149506).

For now enjoy your shiny new badge - you were on the path to earning it anyway.

Comment: Obligatory link to the source of cosmic rays: [Cosmic Rays: what is the probability they will affect a program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580933/cosmic-rays-what-is-the-probability-they-will-affect-a-program) (That's the source of the _meme_ "cosmic rays," not the actual rays themselves, of course.)

Comment: Wonder how many of those rays hit the innocent users over time! :)

Comment: By the way, think we need to add [meta-tag:status-by-cosmic-rays]!