# Lost extra points by downvoting an answer in a deleted topic

Tags: bug

Today I started out with 1817 points. Sometime later I downvoted an answer, which gave me 1816 points (so minus -1). I believe this is normal, right?

Next, some time later, the OP (I assume it was the OP) deleted the topic, which gave me 1815 points. So I lost two points.

According to my Reputation log, this happend:

```
7 > Today
+1 | 9 mins ago | removed | [Topic name]
-1 | 36 mins ago | downvoted | [Topic name]
```

So the first downvote I gave (to an answer), gave me a `-1`. That's the `-1` you see in the log. Then the topic got deleted, which should give me a `+1` (according to the log aswell), but I never got that point. But now I'm left with 2 points fewer.

Is this behaviour normal? Is there any way to test this?

Comment: Give it some time, I remember such thing being reported in the past and it resolved itself after few hours..

Comment: Are you sure you didn't lose 2 points for an unrelated reason?

Comment: I think I recall the same happening to me before and it was some quirky rep cache situation because when I did a reputation recalc, my rep was correct.

Comment: @Servy Yes. I got no downvotes today. I started with `1817`. After i downvoted an answer in that topic i got `-1` (which i'm still not sure if that's suppose to happen?). Then it got deleted and i lost another point. I'm sure nothing else caused this.

Comment: You can try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/reputation for a complete report on your reputation points.

Comment: @w00, the discrepancy might come from another post on which an edit of yours was approved. This resulted in a +2 reputation bonus, and if that post was removed, so is the bonus.

Comment: Take a close look at [your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/874381/w00?tab=reputation), and make sure you have the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom ticked.

Comment: Speaking of reputation, who is [vivendi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1175327/vivendi)?

Comment: Did you edit the question?  if you did and it was approved, you got 2 points for that which you would lose when it was deleted.

Comment: If you accepted an answer to your question and it was deleted you would also lose 2 rep.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi But then the math wouldn't work. Because i got a `-1` from downvoting someone. So that left me with `1816` points. And 3 hours later i had suddenly had `1815` points, because the OP deleted his topic at that moment. And because he deleted it, it should give me the `-1` back that i got from downvoting someone in that topic, right? Because the log clearly says `+1` after the `-1`. But instead of adding it back to my `1816` points, it removed one. So now it i'm left with `1815` points. So it's not a **removed post that i editted** issue.

Comment: @w00, that would be a coincidence, I think. Around the same time the downvoted post was removed (+1 canceling your -1), either another was removed, and you had an accepted suggested edit on it (-2) or one of your questions was removed, and you has accepted an answer on it (also -2, as Servy points out). Did the `show removed posts` check box clarify anything?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It didn't show any removed post.

Comment: Well, the developers can always blame [the cosmic rays](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152728/152859)! ;)

Comment: +1, since I've noticed the exact same thing from my side, with no apparent reason as to why.